# Need to get month column as MM format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different columns like month column and year column in the timetable.

```
year     month
2017      4
2018      5
2017     10
```

But I want to display the output as below

```
year-month
2017-04
2018-05
2017-10
```

for concatenation, I have written code as

```
 select concat(year,'-',month) as period from timetable
```

but I am not able to write code to get month as MM format.Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You want to left pad the data.  Here is one method:

```
select concat(year, '-', right('00' + month, 2)) as period
from timetable
```

This assumes `month` is a string.  Otherwise you need to convert it:

```
select concat(year, '-', right('00' + cast(month as varchar(2)), 2)) as period
from timetable
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** `year` and `month` are an `int`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(4),[year]) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),[month]),2)
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Select Period = stuff([year]*100+[month],5,0,'-')
 From  timetable
```

**Reurns**

```
Period
2017-04
2018-05
2017-10
```

Comment: Yuck!  You are using an implicit conversion from a date to a string.